# How can I solve this second order equation calculation?

Tags: c#

I am working with a simulation and I need to calcuate, at every "time step", some values given by a second order equation.

First, I have this Ordinary Differential Equation that I resolve using Runge-Kutta 4th order numerical method:

```
public static float equation(float t, float annualGrowth)
{
    float y_prime;
    
    float maxLenght = setup.WExt * (1 - (setup.Manager.TotalLenght() / maxTreeHeight));
    y_prime = /*alfaT * */annualGrowth * (1 - (annualGrowth / maxLenght));
    return y_prime;
}
```

Resolved by the method I cited above:

```
    public class Runge 
{
    //declare a delegate that takes a double and returns
    public delegate float Function(float t, float annualGrowth);
    public static float runge(float a, float b, float value, float step, Function f)
    {
        float t, w, k1, k2, k3, k4;
        t = a;
        w = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < (b - a) / step; i++)
        {
            k1 = step * f(t, w);
            k2 = step * f(t + step / 2f, w + k1 / 2f);
            k3 = step * f(t + step / 2f, w + k2 / 2f);
            k4 = step * f(t + step, w + k3);
            w = w + (k1 + 2f * k2 + 2f * k3 + k4) / 6f;
            t = a + i * step;
            //Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", Math.Round(t, 1), w);
        }
        return w;
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, in the equation code block there is a commented parameter (alfaT) that I need to calculate.
The alfaT is function of t (time) over 365 days.
Every day, from 1 to 365, t is calculated as ((180-day)/180)^2 * 2a where a = 25.
Then alfa is = t/a

Now, I need to calculate the t every day (every time step) and pass the value to the first equation (first code block above) as alfaT.
So, I have the ODE calculation step by step and at each step I need to pass the calculated alfaT value at same step. I don't know if I make myself clear...

At the end of 365 alfaT steps, if the ODE continues to run, alfaT needs to start again from 1 (because, of course, a year doesn't have 366, 367, 368, etc days)

Please, could you help me with this? I don't know where and how to start.
Thank you!

EDIT:
Some clarification, I've noticed it was hard fot me to be clear posting the question.
Let's start with the first Ordinary Differential Equation. To solve it, there is the need to use a numerical method, i.e. 4th order RungeKutta, that discretize the differential into finite difference. Each step, the method calculates the approximate value of the solution.

So, when the simulation runs, each "time step" (menaning, for example, every second in the simulation), the approximate solution of the ODE is calculated thanks to RungeKutta numerical method.
This is not my problem because this part works just fine.
My problem is a parameter into the differential equation that is alfaT (commented in the code above)

alfaT is a function of t and is calculated each "time step" (meaning, each step is = 1 day of the year from 1 to 365) as ((180-day)/180)^2 * 2a where a = 25.

So, there are two calculations that should be running at same steps (time steps).
Let's call them T for ODE function and DAY for alfaT, we have:

[image: table]

Notice that if the simulation runs more than 365 steps (time steps), the ODE calculation continues but the alfaT starts ove the 1st day.

Again, the ODE calculation is not the promble, my problem is to calculate the alfaT at same steps of ODE and start over day 1st after the 365th step.

Comment: Is your question about the use of a `delegate`?  Meaning, you want to know how to insert the method `equation` into the method `runge`?  You should be able to write that as: `float result = Runge.runge(a, b, value, step, ClassName.equation);`, where _ClassName_ is the name of the class containing the static method `equation`. This works because the method signature matches that of the expected delegate type.  If that's not your question, try to describe your problem again, maybe by showing your code attempts at _usage_ of these methods.

Comment: Your RK code is slightly wrong (which might not matter in this situation). You need to calculate the `t` as it is at the start of the loop, or use `t = a + (i+1)*step` to get the correct current time.

Comment: Well, I've checked numerically with another software (Simile) and the results are fine. As I mentioned the ODE solution via RK4 is not my problem. I don't know how to calculate the alfaT mentioned above (see also the edit). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to answer this part of your question:

> *"At the end of 365 alfaT steps, if the ODE continues to run, alfaT needs to start again from 1 (because, of course, a year doesn't have 366, 367, 368, etc days)"*

It sounds like you have a value that needs to be bound within a range from `1` to `365`, and wrap from `365` back to `1` as some related number is incremented.

If this is the case, then the modulus operator can help, because it returns the remainder of one number divided by another. So, if we define our max range as `365`, and we add `1` to the result of the modulus, our number will stay within that range:

For example:

```
var minRange = 1;
var maxRange = 365;
        
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // 'value' will start at 'minRange', increment to 'maxRange',
    // and then wrap back to 'minRange' on the next iteration
    var value = i % (maxRange - minRange + 1) + minRange;

    Console.Write($"{value},");
}
```

(please remember, though, that leap years have `366` days)